# Password protecting just one page

Tags: php, html

I'm looking to password protect a specific page on my site (index.html) with PHP code.

Here's what I have right now (this code is C/P from another question on here):

```
<?php
session_start();
$username="admin";
$password="jATPqhu9";

if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password)
{
    header("Location: ecks.html");
    exit;
}
else
{
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style='text-align:center'>
        <h3>Welcome To ---</h3>
        </div>
        <hr /><br />
        <form id='login' action="" method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
            <fieldset style="width:550px">
            <legend>Admin Login</legend>
            <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

            <label for='username' >UserName:</label>
            <input type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" />


            <label for='password' >Password:</label>
            <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />

            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

For some reason, the redirect part (header("Location: ecks.html");) won't redirect to ecks.html.

Comment: Yes. Everything works except the redirect.

Comment: Check your http servers error log file, most likely something is in the output _before_ that head function is called.

Comment: Also taking a look at your browsers console network tab should reveal if that header is sent at all.

Comment: Try to add ob_start() on the top of your page.

Comment: @Sourabh Still doesn't work.
@arkascha I cannot find the log files. Are they in a file that looks like this; `domain.domain-Feb-2017.gz`?

Comment: You said its not redirecting? Did the you to the user's id or name in a `$_SESSION`. `$_SESSION['username'] = $username`. ?

Comment: Just fyi, you aren't actually protecting that page. Anybody can simply go to `http://example.com/ecks.html`.

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah I understand that :P this is just for exercise and some personal stuff.

@Sourabh So I add `ob_start()` after `<?php`, right? Not working when doing that.

@OkeTega Sorry?

Comment: I can't see this failing other than probably outputting before header, or you're using this as `file:///` instead of the host address. Error reporting will tell you if there's anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any use of setting up user name and password in HTML or some other pages it's best to protect it from server side.
to do so, in server, direct towards something like Leach Protection or directory protection or hot link and set password for that there when ever you try to access that page you will require user name and password when ever you access your file on web.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that this isn't secure at all, but I need to set this up this way before securing it further.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
$username="admin";
$password="jATPqhu9";

if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password)
{

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
header("Location: ecks.html");
exit;
}
else
{
    echo "incorrect info.";
}
?>

Put this in the ecks.html page 
<?php 
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    //login html
}
?>
```

Hope this works

Comment: I've updated everything as you said but it still doesn't do anything! Also, the ecks.html part is just to make sure people are logged in when they're viewing ecks.html otherwise they have to log in?